# Is package level annotations still available on EJB3 to map entities on JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, package

**The Problem:**

I have two complementary projects, a base one (Base Project) with shared entities and a specific one (Specific Project) that needs to query the entities from the first project.

They both access the same database, but in different schemes and different users/grants. Nonetheless, both have at least 'SELECT' grant on the shared tables.

I've found three possibilities to integrate them in the Specific Project's persistence.xml:

1. List every single entity from the Base Project using <class> tags in the Specific Projetc's persistence.xml. Downside: every time a new entity comes up it has to be added to the Specific Project to be visible
2. Add the Base Project '.jar' file using a <jar-file> tag in the Specific Project's persistence.xml. Downside: it has to be a real path to the jar file, which may change;
3. (BEST so far) Add the Base Project's entities PACKAGE in the persistence.xml using the <class> tag, as explained in [Hibernate entityManager's setup documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#setup-configuration-packaging). Downside: have to use package level annotations through a package-info.java file, which I can't find anywhere how to do it.

**The Question:**

Does anyone knows if is really possible to use a package level annotation to denote an entity package in the persistence.xml?

The Hibernate documentation states that it can be done, but doesn't tell how:

> **class**
>
> The class element specifies a
>   fully qualified class name that you
>   will map. By default all properly
>   annotated classes and all hbm.xml
>   files found inside the archive are
>   added to the persistence unit
>   configuration. You can add some
>   external entity through the class
>   element though. As an extension to the
>   specification, you can add a package
>   name in the  element (eg
>   org.hibernate.eg).
>   Caution, the package will include the
>   metadata defined at the package level
>   (ie in package-info.java), it will not
>   include all the classes of a given
>   package.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in that [bug report](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/EJB-252), it is working properly. If you want an example of `package-info.java`, you can take a look at [this hibernate forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=983899&view=previous).

**Note:** This functionality is not part of the specification as described in the [persistence XML schema](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd).

```
      <xsd:element name="class" type="xsd:string" 
                   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>

            Class to scan for annotations.  It should be annotated 
            with either @Entity, @Embeddable or @MappedSuperclass.

          </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
```